# After a certain limit it should point to different vm

Tags: nginx

I have a file system in which the files are stored with the numeric number (SQL index) but my VM size is full and I can't shift my files to different Cloud or anything.
My file system URL will be

```
https://example.com/5374/randomstring.jpg
```

5374 is file number which is saved in SQL DB and a random string is generated.

What I'm planning to do is using nginx redirecting right now I have 56770 in a vm if a user tries to upload it will go and save in different vm and if user wants to access 56771 means using nginx it should point to that VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will make your life easier by choosing the cutoff point yourself, it's not essential but it will make matching a regular expression a lot more concise.

If you said 56000 and above was on VM2 then your regex is as simple as `/([5-9][6-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])/`

Comment: I want it to be done using nginx itself. not from code side

Comment: Nginx supports regex based url proxying, this wouldn't require any external processes